# I'm having issues pulling the link to the site from a link list in Sharepoint using the Enhanced Custom Query W/P

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I've created a custom style in my ItemStyle.xsl for displaying a list of links from a links list in SharePoint 2007. The only problem I'm getting is I can pull the link to the item in the list, but I can pull the URL stored within the item in the list. Here is my style:

```
<xsl:template name="LinkListStyled" match="*" mode="itemstyle">
        <xsl:param name="CurPos" />
        <xsl:param name="LastRow" />
        <xsl:variable name="tableStart"> 
             <xsl:if test="$CurPos = 1"> 
                <![CDATA[ 
                <table style="border:0px ; border-collapse:collapse; "> 
                <tr> 
                       <td align="left" width="70px"> 
                       <IMG style="BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px solid; BORDER-LEFT: 0px solid; BORDER-TOP: 0px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px solid" border=0 src="http://intranet.test.co.uk/images/sharepoint_sites/practiceareas/knowhowgreen2.png">
                       </td> 
                       <td align="left"> 
                       <table style="padding:5px">
                   ]]> 
             </xsl:if> 
         </xsl:variable>


         <xsl:variable name="tableEnd"> 
              <xsl:if test="$CurPos = $LastRow"> 
                <![CDATA[
                </table>
                </td> 
                </tr>
                </table>]]> 
              </xsl:if> 


         </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tableStart" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            <xsl:if test="($CurPos mod 2) = 1">
                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
                    <![CDATA[<tr>
                    <td width="2px">
                    <IMG src="http://intranet.test.co.uk/images/sharepoint/green_square_header.gif" />
                    </td>
                    <td width="150px">
                    <a href="
                    ]]>     
                    </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@FileRef"/>
                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
                    <![CDATA["> ]]>
                    </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Title"></xsl:value-of>

                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
                    <![CDATA[</a></td>]]>
                    </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="($CurPos mod 2) = 0">
                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
                    <![CDATA[
                    <td width="2px">
                    <IMG src="http://intranet.test.co.uk/images/sharepoint/green_square_header.gif" />
                    </td>
                    <td width="150px">
                    ]]>
                    </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Title"></xsl:value-of><br />

                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
                    <![CDATA[</td>
                    </tr>]]>
                    </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>   
            <xsl:value-of select="$tableEnd" disable-output-escaping="yes" />       
    </xsl:template>
```

I have tried using the same methods as in the LinkList style:

```
    <xsl:variable name="DisplayTitle">        
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetTitle">            
            <xsl:with-param name="Title" select="@URL"/>            
            <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'URL'"/>        
        </xsl:call-template>    
    </xsl:variable>
```

But the moment I add this into my style it breaks the view. Oddly, if I put a call to the OuterTemplate outside my style and then reference the values in my style it doesn't fall over and I can pull through the values, however this doesn't work for URL (I'm guessing this is because it needs to pull through a title to retrieve the URL). I've tried a few different things but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the 'URL,text' into the Custom Field View in the web part.